# Using Caliburn.Micro to bind to sub-properties

Tags: silverlight, caliburn.micro

I'm using Caliburn.Micro and I would like to be able to do something like the following...

```
<TextBlock x:Name="User.Name"></TextBlock>
```

However this won't compile because xaml doesn't allow names to contain a "."

What is the preferred solution here? Do I just revert to standard databinding syntax?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should use User_Name.